# Copy row values from one worksheet to another in increments

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets. In one worksheet named "Equipment details" I have a set of values in column A, rows 13 to 1000. I want to copy each of these values, namely A13, A14, A15 and so forth in to another worksheet named "Workshet(2)" starting at cell A2. However, the trick is A13 from the first worksheet needs to be copied into A2 of the second worksheet, A14 to A8, A15 to A14 and so on in increments of 6 each time. The following is my code but it does not work. It copies the first record from A13 to A2 but then goes all awry. Please help!

```
Sub CopyData2()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim srcws As Worksheet
    Set srcws = wb.Worksheets("Equipment details")
    Dim destws As Worksheet
    Set destws = wb.Worksheets("Worksheet (2)")
    Dim frstRec As Long
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim SrcRowNo As Integer
    Dim DestRowNo As Integer
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = destws.Range("a2")
    'Source sheet starting row
    SrcRowNo = 13
    'Destination sheet starting row
    DestRowNo = 2
    'Copy and paste first record into destination sheet
    srcws.Cells(SrcRowNo, 1).Copy Destination:=destws.Cells(DestRowNo, 1)
    frstRec = myRange.Row
    For SrcRowNo = 13 To 50
        For frstRec = 2 To 50
            srcws.Cells(SrcRowNo + 1, 1).Copy Destination:=destws.Cells(frstRec, 1)
        Next frstRec
    Next SrcRowNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there values in the second worksheet in column A (already)?

Comment: Nope. the cells are all blank but all columns alongside col A have values to which these copied valued must match to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CopyData2()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim srcws As Worksheet
    Set srcws = wb.Worksheets("Equipment details")
    Dim destws As Worksheet
    Set destws = wb.Worksheets("Worksheet (2)")
    Dim RowNo As Long

    For RowNo = 0 To 987
        srcws.Cells(RowNo + 13, 1).Copy Destination:=destws.Cells(RowNo*6 + 2, 1)
    Next RowNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Be careful running that. it works, I think, but it crashed my excel. needs to be looped into an array I believe

Comment: Just tested it and it works fine on my machine

Comment: Might be my setup with 365

Comment: Thank you! That worked. However, it pasted the values in the wrong rows but I changed it to *7 and worked fine. However, it takes a long time to run the code but it works.

Comment: If my answer works for you, you can mark it as correct, so others know your problem is solved. Also, we don't do this for free ;)

Comment: Sorry but where do I mark it as correct?

Comment: There`s a big checkmark to the left of your question

Comment: Done! Also, was wondering if you could help with step 2 of my code. Now that I have the values copying over in the right sequence from the first sheet to the second, I now need to copy the value in A2 of the second sheet to the next 6 rows under A2 and then copy the value in A8 to the next 6 rows under A8 and so on. This is the code I have but it works only partially in that it keeps overwriting the values in A3 to A7:

Comment: Dim wb As Workbook
     Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     Dim destws As Worksheet
        Set destws = wb.Worksheets("Worksheet (2)")
       Dim RowNo2 As Long
       Dim RowNo3 As Long
      For RowNo2 = 1 To 2000
    For RowNo3 = 1 To 6
 
    destws.Cells(RowNo2 * 7 - 5, 1).Copy Destination:=destws.Cells(RowNo3 * 1 + 2, 1)
    
     
     Next RowNo3
Next RowNo2

Comment: Code is very hard to parse in comments. You'd probably be better off asking a new question explaining things in detail. Also, which answer did you mean to mark as correct?

Comment: Sorry marked the correct one now as complete. I added the second question to this same thread as they are connected. Will try and redo it

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CopyData2()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSrc = wb.Worksheets("Equipment details")
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Worksheet (2)")
    
    ' copy A13->A2, A14->A8, A15->A14
    Const INCR = 6
    Const START_ROW = 13
    Const END_ROW = 1000
    Dim arSrc, arDest, i As Long, j As Long
    
    arSrc = wsSrc.Range("A" & START_ROW & ":A" & END_ROW).Value2
    arDest = wsDest.Range("A2:A" & INCR * UBound(arSrc)).Value2
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arSrc)
        j = 1 + (i - 1) * INCR
        arDest(j, 1) = arSrc(i, 1)
    Next
    wsDest.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arDest)) = arDest
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```